# different highlight if a certain highlight is on

Tags: vimscript, highlight

I'm writing a function to highlight current word, but on commented out lines, I want a different highlight to apply.

Example:
[image: highlight]

Notice how the word `exists` is highlighed, but on a grey commented out line it's too bright:
[image: highlight]

Here's the function:

```
function! s:HighlightWordUnderCursor()
  let disabled_ft = [
        \'qf',
        \'fugitive',
        \'nerdtree',
        \'gundo',
        \'diff',
        \'fzf',
        \'floaterm',
        \'vim-plug'
  \]
  let disabled_buftypes = ['terminal', 'quickfix', 'help']
  let nohl_conditions = getline('.')[col('.')-1] =~# '[[:punct:][:blank:]]' || &diff || index(disabled_buftypes, &buftype) >= 0 || index(disabled_ft, &filetype) >= 0

  if !nohl_conditions
    hi MatchWord cterm=undercurl ctermbg=240 gui=undercurl guibg=#665c54
    exec 'match MatchWord /\V\<' . substitute(expand('<cword>'), '/', '\/', 'g') . '\>/'
  else
    match none
  endif
endfunction

augroup MatchWord
  autocmd!
  autocmd! CursorHold,CursorHoldI * call <SID>HighlightWordUnderCursor()
augroup END
```

Is there a way to identify the highlight of `<cword>` to have a custom highlighting of commented out lines?
Thanks.

Comment: you need to check the current syntax item at a position and depending on the output (e.g. the syntax item matches `Comment`). Something along the lines of `:echo map(synstack(line("."), col(".")), 'synIDattr(v:val, "name")')`

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt this does not echo the applied highlight groups for some reason.. for example, when searching for a word and then running the echo, I expect to see `["Search"]` highlight

Comment: the `Search` highlighting is a totally different highlighting mechanism than syntax highlighting. Same thing for using the `match` function/commands or `sign` commands or text property. So yes, that is expected :/

Comment: Any way to catch those?

Comment: depends on what you want to do. For search highlighting, you may need to check if you are on a search match and `v:hlsearch` is true. For matches, I don't know of an easy way to do it (again you would need to check whether the cursor is on a match), for text_properties, I don't know at all, for signs I would say it is such a rare use-case, that the line is also highlighted, that I wouldn't bother, for visual mode(), it should be possible to check the `mode()`.